# click on svg element is not working in cypress

Tags: highcharts, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am having a scenario to click on a svg element, tried the following code, it is not throwing any error. it is clicking but the element state is not changed. tried force click also.

```js
cy.xpath("(//app-job[contains(@class,'selected')]//highcharts-chart[@id='GMF_K_CHART']//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g' and @class='highcharts-series-group']//*[name()='g' and @clip-path='none' and not(@visibility)])[4]//*[name()='path'][4]")
            .click()
```

[Graph how displaying after clcik](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVoDE.png)

[But it should be if clicked properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDe6U.png)

I tried multiple combination of clicks
`.click({force: true})

```
        .click()
        .trigger('change')

        .trigger('focus')
        .click()`
```

Comment: In the beginning, make sure that `cy.xpath()` is getting the element you expect. It may find `chart.container`, which won't return an error, but it's not the element you want. You can try the `cy.get()` method to get the point as well, and then use `.click({force: true})` on it.

Comment: Yes it is finding the exact element, click is happening but the field is not enabled. only by using xpath alone able to track the element. not able to locate by native cypress locating strategy `cy.get()`. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you're selecting the svg element and then, use trigger() to click on that element.

```
    cy.get('<svg element>').trigger('click')
```

Comment: Do you mean `cy.get('svg').trigger('click')`? A `<button>` element is not `<svg>`. Can you explain why `.trigger('click')` improves things?

Comment: It's not working for me either.  `.trigger('click')` would only be useful if you needed to specify the click event parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that cypress expects that click is preceded by mouse hover. In that case, make sure that cypress hovers the mouse over the point (the tooltip must fire) and then let the cypress perform a click event on the point.

```
  cy.get(".highcharts-container")
    .get(".highcharts-point")
    .eq(1)
    .trigger("mousemove");
  cy.wait(1000);
  cy.get(".highcharts-container")
    .get(".highcharts-point")
    .eq(1)
    .trigger("click");
```

If that didn't work, it would be possible that some cypress event is not correctly triggered; in that case try the following workaround:

```
cy.get(".highcharts-container")
        .get(".highcharts-point")
        .eq(1)
        .trigger("mousemove").trigger("mousemove");
      cy.wait(1000);
      cy.get(".highcharts-container")
        .get(".highcharts-point")
        .eq(1)
        .trigger("click").trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got an app with a chart and tried this to click on the first data point and it worked:

```js
cy.get(`.highcharts-container`) //chart container
.find(`.highcharts-root`)       //actual chart
.find(`.highcharts-point`)      //data-point
.eq(0)                          //first data-point
.as('dataPoint');
cy.get(`@dataPoint`).trigger('mousemove').wait(500); //hover over item
cy.get(`@dataPoint`).click().wait(500);              //NOW click it
```

The tooltip should become visible now!